# Why does preventDefault stop working when I try to use a function passed by props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preventdefault

I have a component with a form and when I use this line of code the function passed by props works.

`<form onSubmit={this.props.onCreateNewItem.bind(this)}>`

If I try to create another function before the render that will run onCreateNewItem it stops working.

`<form action="" onSubmit={this.onChangeTest}>`

```
onChangeTest(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.onCreateNewItem();
  }
```

If I run the code with out trying to call the function then the preventDefault works. If I try to run the function I get this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined." I tried to bind this and then preventDefault works but it does not run the function.

`this.props.onCreateNewItem.bind(this);`

I am confused because I can get the preventDefault to work without calling the function and I can get the function to work if I call it directly in the form but I can not get them both to work together.

Comment: Can you share your entire component code? Perhaps a jsfiddle.

Comment: It's hard to say what's going on without seeing more code from these components, but it sounds the function passed as the `onCreateNewItem` prop is calling `preventDefault` on its argument, expecting it to be an event object. In which case replacing `this.props.onCreateNewItem()` with `this.props.onCreateNewItem(event)` should at least remove the error shown.

Comment: By the way, I'm suspicious about this: `<form onSubmit={this.props.onCreateNewItem.bind(this)}>` - that is, the binding of a function prop to the child component's own `this`. Perhaps it works, but it might be completely unnecessary (if it doesn't use `this` at all) - it feels like an antipattern to do this so I'm interested in seeing the code and in particular what you are passing as that prop.

Comment: @RobinZigmond You were right! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You have to `bind` 'onChangeTest' method. Currently the `this` inside `onChangeTest` is referring to the `form` object not React component.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onChangeTest = this.onChangeTest.bind(this);
  }

  onChangeTest(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.onCreateNewItem();
  }

  render() {
   return (
    <form action="" onSubmit={this.onChangeTest}>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
   );
  }
}

///
function onCreateNewItem() {
    console.log("onCreateNewItem called")
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App onCreateNewItem={onCreateNewItem} />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```